# putting javascript functions in count loop

Tags: javascript, php

So here's what I'm trying to do. I need to create new javascript functions to go with the table contents so I can edit the table contents individually when they are created. However, my problem is I am getting an Uncaught Error: Object is not a function. Whenever I call the function.

Anyone have any idea why?

```
while($inventorynumber>$q){
    echo '<script>function edititem'.$q.'(){document.getElementById("edititem'.$q.'").innerHTML = ""; document.getElementById("edititem'.$q.'").innerHTML = "<input class=\"number\" type=\"number\" placeholder=\"'.$item[$q].'\" name=\"item'.$q.'\"></input>";}

    function editdesc'.$q.'(){document.getElementById("editdesc'.$q.'").innerHTML = ""; document.getElementById("editdesc'.$q.'").innerHTML = "<input class=\"number\" type=\"number\" placeholder=\"'.$desc[$q].'\" name=\"desc'.$q.'"></input>\";}

    function editprice'.$q.'(){document.getElementById("editprice'.$q.'").innerHTML = ""; document.getElementById("editprice'.$q.'").innerHTML = "<input class=\"number\" type=\"number\" placeholder=\"'.$price[$q].'\" name=\"price'.$q.'\"></input>";}

    function editquantity'.$q.'(){document.getElementById("editquantity'.$q.'").innerHTML = ""; document.getElementById("editquantity'.$q.'").innerHTML = "<input class=\"number\" type=\"number\" placeholder=\"'.$quantity[$q].'\" name=\"quantity'.$q.'\"></input>";}

    </script>';
    if ($invtotal[$q]==$number) {
        $invdate=$date[$q];
        $item_total = (($quantity[$q])*($price[$q]));
        $quantities = $quantity[$q];
        echo '<tr><td id="edititem'.$q.'"><a onClick="edititem'.$q.'()">'.$item[$q].'</a></td><td id="editdesc'.$q.'"><a onClick="editdesc'.$q.'()">'.$desc[$q].'</a></td><td id="editprice'.$q.'">$<a onClick="editprice'.$q.'()">'.$price[$q].'</a></td><td id="editquantity'.$q.'"><a onClick="editquantity'.$q.'()">'.$quantity[$q].'</a></td><td>$'.$item_total.'</td></tr>';
        $sum_total += $item_total;
        $quantity_total += $quantities;
        $q++;
    }
    else {
        $q++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you defining functions inside a loop? Wouldn't it better to have only a function, and call that multiple times with different parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that above code outputs script tag between table and tr rows, which is invalid place ( only tr tags can be nested inside of table )

You need to change the code to output the script section before or after table tag.

Comment: Thats is not completely true. Inside a table you can have `thead` and `tbody` as well.

Comment: You are right, but in context of question - script tag can't be placed on the same level as TR tag anyway.

Comment: Can't find any way of doing that and have the count work the way that I need to. I'm going to look into calling the JS function with parametrs as Damien suggested. Thanks tho